# Inherit height of div from inner elements

Tags: css, html

How can I inherite height of `<div>` acting as a wrapper from innter elements?

like,

Height of wrapper = total height of inner elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the `div` the `overflow: auto` CSS attribute.